# Condition if zero or less - working with if 0 but unsure or is less

Tags: php, smarty

I have the following code :

```
{if $product.amount == 0}
      <div class="ofs-label">{$lang.price}:</div>
{/if}
```

which at the moment shows the HTML if the amount is equal to 0, however, how can I modify this so it shows the HTML if it is equal to 0 or less?

Comment: Do you not know the operator to use or do you not understand the syntax for comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at comparison operators in PHP. Here's a [great resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) from php.net

For your purpose, you would want to do this:

```
{if $product.amount <= 0}
<div class="ofs-label">{$lang.price}:</div>
{/if}
```

As you can see, the <= operator will return `TRUE` if `$product.amount` is less than or equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i ended up doing - almost 1am and been at is 18 hours to finish this project must be getting tired! will mark your answer for your time though :)

Comment: Thanks! If you think my answer is the best, please also mark it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

like PHP, you can use

> <=

```
{if $product.amount <= 0}
  <div class="ofs-label">{$lang.price}:</div>
  {/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if $product.amount <= 0
```

Here is a fast snippet of logical operators.

```
== Equality
!= Inequality
<  Less Than
<= Less or Equal Than
>  Greater
=> Greater or Equal
```

For more information have a look at [this reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).